# distm function, to compare a list of 2 coordinates (2 sets of long/lat coordinates) and find distance between them

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

I have two sets of data that are longitude and latitude coordinates. For example, I have 100 address and their long/lats, then I have 200 long/lats of wells. I want to be able to calculate the distance of each address to each well. So I want to know how far away address 1 is from each of the 200 wells, then how far address 2 is from each of the 200 wells... exc.

I have tried distm function, however it always comes up that my vector is more than two.. my data is formatted incorrectly... etc

```
library(geosphere)
distm (c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Does anyone have recomendations on how to approach this or fix my data set to run distm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `lon-lat` data should be provided as a matrix when you have sets of coordinates :

```r
library(geosphere)
data("wrld")

lat1 <- wrld[1:4,"Latitude"]
lon1 <- wrld[1:4,"Longitude"]

lat2 <- wrld[11:15,"Latitude"]
lon2 <- wrld[11:15,"Longitude"]

distm(matrix(c(lon1,lat1),ncol=2), matrix(c(lon2,lat2),ncol=2), fun = distHaversine)
#>         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
#> [1,] 6655682 6818038 6866664 6961118 7159195
#> [2,] 6668641 6830962 6879683 6973962 7172070
#> [3,] 6656844 6819165 6867886 6962165 7160273
#> [4,] 6655682 6818038 6866664 6961118 7159195
```

Comment: @Ashleigh Tindle, did you try and get the expected result?